# Помогите найти ошибку в коде PHP8

Tags: php, opencart, php8

```
 $this->load->language('extension/shipping/free');
        $data['entry_total'] = $this->language->get('entry_total');
        $price_delivery = $data['entry_total'];

        $data['price_total'] = $price_total;
        $delivery_free = $price_total < $price_delivery ? false : true;
       // $delivery_free = $price_total < 4000 ? false : true;
        $delivery_sum_free = $price_delivery - $price_total;
       // $delivery_sum_free = 4000 - $price_total;

        $data['delivery_free'] = $delivery_free;
        $data['delivery_sum_free'] = $delivery_sum_free;
```

Я тут пытался вывести переменную из другого файла, но выходит ошибка A non-numeric value encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка вероятно в строке

```
$delivery_sum_free = $price_delivery - $price_total;
```

Вы получили данные из $data['entry_total'] или(и) $price_total в формате строки.
Продебажте эти 2 переменные перед манипуляций ими при помощи var_dump.

Если там числа как строка, то их можно привести в числовое значение при помощи конструкций

```
$num = "3.14";
$int = (int)$num;
$float = (float)$num;
```

Есть функция is_numeric($var), ей можно проверить, является ли переменная числовой.